# Position of a cell next to a checkbox

Tags: excel

I want to add the value of a cell next to a chekbox to a sum, like this :

[image: exemple]

First I tried to return the value of the cell next to a checkbox and I found dificulties writing the position of this cell next to my checkbox.

I used "left" and "top" as following:

```
Sub Caseàcocher_Cliquer()

    Dim ligne As Integer
    Dim colonne As Integer

    ligne = 4
    colonne = 3 

    If [Case à cocher 1].Value = 1 Then

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ligne, colonne).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ligne, colonne).Value + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells([Case à cocher 1].Left, [Case à cocher 1].Top + 2).Value

    Else: [ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ligne, colonne).Value] = [ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ligne, colonne).Value]
```

I started VBA yesterday and I don't find out the correct writing.

This part is wrong but I don't know why and how to replace it :

```
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells([Case à cocher 1].Left, [Case à cocher 1].Top + 2).Value'
```

Comment: Why is Option 3 apparently associated with the cell beside Option 2?

Comment: It is not meant to be

Comment: The image is an exemple, i checked the wrong box it should be OPTION2 being checked in order to get 5. But that's the point, if my code worked, the result would be 9 in the case of the image I shared